# How to start Symfony through app.php?

Tags: php, symfony

```
http://localhost/Symfony/web/app.php/demo/hello/Alex
```

shows

> "Cannot import resource "@AcmeDemoBundle/Controller/SecuredController.php" from "D:/UserData/WWWRoot/Symfony/app/config/routing.yml". Make sure the "AcmeDemoBundle/Controller/SecuredController.php" bundle is correctly registered and loaded in the application kernel class."

This is my routes of `app\config\routing.yml`

Internal routing configuration to handle ESI

```
_internal:
    resource: "@FrameworkBundle/Resources/config/routing/internal.xml"
    prefix:   /_internal

_welcome:
    pattern:  /
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:Welcome:index }

_demo_secured:
    resource: "@AcmeDemoBundle/Controller/SecuredController.php"
    type:     annotation

_demo:
    resource: "@AcmeDemoBundle/Controller/DemoController.php"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /demo
```

Comment: Have you tried `app/console router:debug`? to see if the routes are set properly?

Comment: How ? I use Apache on Windows, ive copied routes from app\config\routing_DEV.yml

Comment: So whats your question actually?

Comment: How to fix the problem ""Cannot import resource "@AcmeDemoBundle/Controller/SecuredController.php" from "D:/UserData/WWWRoot/Symfony/app/config/routing.yml". Make sure the "AcmeDemoBundle/Controller/SecuredController.php" bundle is correctly registered and loaded in the application kernel class.""

Comment: Check whether the system's environment variable `PATH` contains your php folder. I guess xampp does this during install, but I am not sure. You can test it by calling `php -v` in your command line. If it works, i.e. you see some version information, navigate to your project's root and type `php app\console router:debug --env=prod` this should print all routes available in your production environment, i.e. which are accessible via app.php. If some are missing, try `php app\console cache:clear --env=prod` to update the cache, if this doesn't help either report back

Comment: Also, by default the AcmeDemoBundle is registered as a dev-bundle. You might have forgotten to move it to the default bundles in your `AppKernel.php`. This is actually more likely, than a routing problem. Must have missed that error message, when reading your question the first time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AcmeDemoBundle` is activated in `AppKernel` for `dev` and `test` environments only:

```php
if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), array('dev', 'test'))) {
    $bundles[] = new Acme\DemoBundle\AcmeDemoBundle();
}
```

If you want to access it via `app.php` — which is for the `prod` envifonment — you need to move the bundle activation out of the condition.

Comment: Thanks it work !, i've replace array with an array('dev', 'test', 'prod'). Спасибо земляк. Можно еще пару вопросов куда нить в личку тебе ?

Comment: You can find me in IRC on the `#symfony` channel at freenode.

Comment: Adding the `prod` environment to that condition is not a good idea because other bundles not meant for production are activated there.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, adding prod in the `getEnvironment()` options array is OK, assuming you know what bundles dont go to prod.

Have a separate condition to check if its dev or test for other bundles that don't go to prod